# can not getUniformLocation of cc.UNIFORM_ALPHA_TEST_VALUE_S?

Tags: javascript, ios, opengl-es, webgl, cocos2d-x

`gl.getUniformLocation(this._glprogram, cc.UNIFORM_ALPHA_TEST_VALUE_S)` returns -1
 in cocos2d-x-2.2.1 js binding on iOS, it works well in html5 version.

Is it a bug or any other way I can get `UNIFORM_ALPHA_TEST_VALUE_S` location?

I also checked its test case in "Sprite: openGL Z vertex" of samples/Javascript/Shared/tests/SpriteTest/SpriteTest.js, it has the same problem.

```
    var alphaTestShader = cc.ShaderCache.getInstance().getProgram("ShaderPositionTextureColorAlphaTest");
    var glprogram = alphaTestShader.getProgram();
    var alphaValueLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(glprogram, cc.UNIFORM_ALPHA_TEST_VALUE_S);
    cc.log(alphaValueLocation);
```

Comment: you need to change your title

Comment: Did you check for gl Errors?  you may also need to show us some code.

Comment: The console just prints out "CC_AlphaValue". cocos2dx' test case has the same issue.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by cocos2d js bindings v.s. html5? Is this running on the same target platform? Or are you comparing iOS v.s. desktop?

Comment: js binding's backend is cocos2dx (c++ code), html5's backend is cocos2d-html5 (javascript code). I am not comparing iOS v.s. desktop, I just like to develop/debug with google-chrome browser, so I use html5 just for develop/debug.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is that UNIFORM_ALPHA_TEST_VALUE_S has wrong value.

```
cc.UNIFORM_ALPHA_TEST_VALUE_S   = 'CC_AlphaValue';  // wrong
```

=>

```
cc.UNIFORM_ALPHA_TEST_VALUE_S   = 'CC_alpha_value'; // correct
```